# Dockerfile for Yesod deployment

Tags: docker, yesod

I am working on a Yesod app which I would like to deploy using Docker. I am using `stack` for building and the app works as expected when interacting locally using `stack exec -- yesod devel`. I would now like to put this on a remote server, using Docker for deployment.

I realize that I can either

1. Have the Dockerfile orchestrate the compilation and build locally
2. Put the binary inside a Docker image, push image up to a repository, and pull to server.

Assuming going route #2, I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM haskell:7.10

MAINTAINER stevejb <stevejb>

RUN mkdir /yesodapp
COPY config /yesodapp/config
COPY static /yesodapp/static
COPY ./.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/sjb-app/sjb-app /yesodapp/sjb-app

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/yesodapp/sjb-app"]
```

However, this does not do anything. When I try to start the app manually from within the container, it does not do anything. I think I am missing something simple here.

---

In `stack.yaml`,

```
image:
    container:
        name: stevejb/sjb-app
        base: fpco/stack-run
        add:
            config: /app/config
            static: /app/static
```

Then,

```
$ stack image container
Sending build context to Docker daemon 30.08 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM fpco/stack-run
 ---> db9b2a858ef5
Step 1 : ADD ./ /
 ---> 69d4ae832c0e
Removing intermediate container 4c6dd4edc16d
Successfully built 69d4ae832c0e
$ $ docker run --rm  -p 3000:3000 stevejb/sjb-app
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 17
*** Running sudo -EHu root PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /usr/bin/env -- bash...
*** sudo exited with status 0.
*** Shutting down runit daemon (PID 17)...
*** Killing all processes...
```

Also, I noticed that this does not generate a `Dockerfile`. Is the [yesodweb dockerfile](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesodweb.com/blob/master/Dockerfile) made by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First guess would be that you need to change your working directory to `/yesodapp`.

Since you're already using Stack, you may be interested in trying out its Docker container generation capabilities. An example is in the [yesodweb.com code base](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesodweb.com). In the stack.yaml file, we have:

```
resolver: lts-3.0
image:
    container:
        name: snoyberg/yesodweb
        base: fpco/stack-run
        add:
            config: /app/config
            static: /app/static
```

Then running `stack image container` generates a `snoyberg/yesodweb` Docker image.

You may also be interested in checking out the [Kubernetes deployment scripts](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesodweb.com/tree/master/kube) I use for yesodweb.com.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you so much for answering, and for yesod itself! I am putting an edit in the comment. I think I am close but not quote there yet.

Comment: I ended up slighly modifying the Dockerfile on yesodweb. Also, I did not realize that production apps run on 3332 by default, rather than 3000, but I got that sorted on #yesod on IRC quickly. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I'm still confused. @stevejb I have the same problem. I'm not using yesode, but a wai/warp app running on port 8003, but there's nothing started on my port. How did you get it to work?